# Using javascript only, i would like to select a thumbnail in one div and open it in another div with accompanying text

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am new to Javascript and have been tasked to create a gallery page of images. Becuase of my company's technological limitations I can only write in JavaScript (no jQuery - it causes accessibility problems) and the solution must be compatible with IE8 (I know!).
I have a series of thumbnail images with a small amount of text in one div, and I need to click on a thumbnail to show a larger image with a large amount of text in another div. When a second thumbnail is selected it must replace (i.e.close any previous large images and text) and display it's own large image and associated text.

I have tried a few solutions but the problem is I can either:
- get the images to replace each other, but not the text (i.e. the first text stays showing)?
or,
- get the correct image and text to show, but they appear stacked rather than replacing each other. (This was using a show/hide script).

The script that replaces the img is very simple, but I don't know how to adapt to to pick up the div instead of just the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLarge(srcLarge)
{
    document.getElementById("large").src = srcLarge;
}
</script>

<img src="/path/to/thumb1.jpg" onclick="showLarge('/path/to/large1.jpg')"/>
<img src="/path/to/thumb2.jpg" onclick="showLarge('/path/to/large2.jpg')"/>
<img src="/path/to/thumb3.jpg" onclick="showLarge('/path/to/large3.jpg')"/>

<img id="large" src="/path/to/large1.jpg"/>
```

The show/hide script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>
```

...and I would like this to be adapted for when a div is showing, and a second thumbnail is selected; then the second thumbnail replaces the first instead of just appearing underneath.

Like I said, I'm very new to this, I hope this helps.
Many thanks.

Comment: Add the code and we might be able to debug it.

Comment: Code... We need code!

Comment: jQuery causes accessibility problems? More-so than regular JavaScript? I...what's the source for this claim?

Comment: Like it or not, IE8 is the most popular IE version right now (Windows XP is the 2nd most popular OS and can't upgrade beyond IE8).  Implying that IE8 is some archaic browser that can't possibly do things like replace nodes, modify attributes, load images, process events, or walk the DOM without the aid of jQuery is a little sad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `onclick` in the `img` elements you are clicking.

You could store the text information in the images with a `data-` attribute.

On click, you can grab the `src` of the `img` along with the `data-` attribute, and then write a new element to the `DOM` using that information.

http://jsbin.com/OtEPorI/1/edit